# Large sample statistics - normal distribution assumption

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

In large sample statistics, the normal distribution is often assumed because of the CLT, i.e., as wikipedia states: "Since real-world quantities are often the balanced sum of many unobserved random events, the central limit theorem also provides a partial explanation for the prevalence of the normal probability distribution".

Why is this true? Beyond the Galton experiment, what justifies this assumption? Is there a proof for this or is it just an epistemological justification?

Comment: It seems that you are confusing a few things. The Central Limit Theorem is a mathematical theorem, so that means it is true in the mathematical realm. The wikipedia page then explains that many real-world phenomena is known (empirically) to be affected by many random disturbances, so it is the sum of such disturbances, hence it should be approximately normal distribution. Further, it is also known (empirically) that the normal distribution fits or models well (whatever "well" means here) real-world data. There is nothing else, specially not philosophy. Let us not taint maths with philosophy.

Comment: "In large sample statistics, the normal distribution is often assumed because of the CLT" is often misunderstood.  It is the distribution of statistics such as the sum or mean (or others for which the Delta method can be used) that can have an approximately normal distribution when the sample size is large, and not necessarily the distribution of the sample values themselves